# How to get starting and ending days of each month in a date interval in js

Tags: javascript

i'm looking for a function which takes as parameters a starting and an ending date that returns an array of each first/ending days for each months in this interval.

Expected :

```
myFunction(new Date('2021-02-06'), new Date('2021-04-24'))
```

Expected output :

```
[
  {begin: '2021-02-06', end: '2021-02-28' },
  {begin: '2021-03-01', end: '2021-03-31' },
  {begin: '2021-04-01', end: '2021-04-24' },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code:

```
myFunction(new Date('2021-02-06'), new Date('2021-04-24'));

function myFunction(startDateInput, endDateInput) {

      var monthDifference = monthDiff(startDateInput, endDateInput)
      var dates = [];

      for (var i = 0; i <= monthDifference; i++) {
          var month = startDateInput.getMonth();
          var year = startDateInput.getFullYear();

          // this gets first day in month
          var startDate = new Date(year, month + i, 1)
          // this gets last day in month
          var endDate = new Date(year, month + i + 1, 0)

          console.log('startDate', startDate);
          console.log('endDate', endDate);

          dates.push(
            {
              begin : startDate,
              end : endDate
            }
          )
      }

      // this is to overwrite first and last date in array, it can be done better
      dates[0].begin = startDateInput;
      dates[monthDifference].end = endDateInput;

      console.log('dates', dates)

  }

  function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
      var months;
      months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
      months -= d1.getMonth();
      months += d2.getMonth();
      return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
  }
```

Of course you can improve this code further. I made it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const formatDateString = (date) => {
  const leadingZero = (d) => (100 + d + '').substr(1);
  const y = date.getFullYear();
  const m = leadingZero(date.getMonth() + 1);
  const d = leadingZero(date.getDate());
  return `${y}-${m}-${d}`;
};
const myFunction = (startIn, endIn) => {
  const monthDifference = monthsDist(startIn, endIn);
  const res = [];

  const startYear = startIn.getFullYear();
  const startMonth = startIn.getMonth();
  const startDate = startIn.getDate();

  for (let deltaM = 0; deltaM <= monthDifference; deltaM++) {
    const monthStart = new Date(
      startYear,
      startMonth + deltaM,
      deltaM ? 1 : startDate
    );

    const monthEnd =
      deltaM < monthDifference ?
      new Date(startYear, startMonth + deltaM + 1, 0) :
      endIn;

    res.push({
      begin: formatDateString(monthStart),
      end: formatDateString(monthEnd),
    });
  }

  return res;
};

const monthsDist = (start, end) => {
  const diffM =
    (end.getFullYear() - start.getFullYear()) * 12 +
    end.getMonth() -
    start.getMonth();
  return diffM > 0 ? diffM : 0;
};

console.log(myFunction(new Date('2021-02-06'), new Date('2021-04-24')));
console.log(myFunction(new Date('2020-02-06'), new Date('2021-04-24')));
console.log(myFunction(new Date('2021-04-06'), new Date('2021-04-24')));
```